# Número maior e menor

Tags: java

Preciso ordenar três números sendo que não posso utilizar `for` e nem vetores.

Sei que é fácil mas não consigo fazer. Meu problema é: não consigo guardar o maior valor.

```
     public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int menor = 0;
    int maior = 0;
    System.out.println(" Tres números:");
    int a = sc.nextInt();
    int b = sc.nextInt();
    int c = sc.nextInt();



    if((a < b) && (a < c))
        menor = a;

    else if((b < a)&&(b < c))
        menor = b;

    else if((c < a)&&(c < b))
        menor = c;

    System.out.println(" Maior: " + maior + " Menor:" + menor);
}
```

Opa acho que consegui resolver.

```
if((a < b) && (a < c))
        menor = a;

    else if((b < a)&&(b < c))
        menor = b;

    else if((c < a)&&(c < b))
        menor = c;

    if((a > b) && (a > c))
        maior = a;

    else if((b > a)&&(b > c))
        maior = b;

    else if((c > a)&&(c > b))
        maior = c;
    System.out.println(" Maior: " + maior + " Menor:" + menor);
}
```

Comment: switch case pode?

Comment: Sim. Mas acho que resolvi, olha se está certo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma forma simples seria esta:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Ideone {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(" Tres números:");
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        int b = sc.nextInt();
        int c = sc.nextInt();
        int menor = a;
        int maior = a;
        if (b > maior) maior = b;
        if (c > maior) maior = c;
        if (b < menor) menor = b;
        if (c < menor) menor = c;
        System.out.println(" Maior: " + maior + " Menor: " + menor);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/fN2pkr). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ipgqicsy-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/LessGreather.java).

Obviamente tem outras formas de fazer isto, mas essa é simples.

Comment: O que é Integer.MAX_VALUE;?

Comment: Fiquei p da vida por não conseguir sacar de imediato uma lógica pra isso sem usar laço, fiz até diagrama com < e > pra entender e a solução era tão simples kkk me sinto um inciante

Comment: @AlineGonzaga Simplifiquei e não precisa mais dele. Ele seria a constante com o maior valor de um inteiro.

Comment: Entendi  o jeito que você fez, bigown. Gostei. as variáveis vao modificando...

Comment: Eu não to lembrado, mas em java se a entrada for `123 456 789`, ele atribui direto as três variáveis ou ele só considera o primeiro?

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert Ele separa em três entradas distintas.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert, nesse caso, o espaço em branco será o delimitador. Portanto, cada numero inteiro irá para cada uma das variáveis.

Answer (score 4):

Uma outra opção seria essa:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Ideone {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(" Tres números:");
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        int b = sc.nextInt();
        int c = sc.nextInt();
        int menor;
        int maior;

        maior = Math.max(b,Math.max(c,a));
        menor = Math.min(b,Math.min(c,a));

        System.out.println(" Maior: " + maior + " Menor: " + menor);
    }
}
```

A expressão abaixo utiliza a função `Math.max` para obter o maior valor entre dois valores. Primeiro, compara-se `c` com `a`. Logo depois, compara-se o resultado disso com `b`. No final, o maior entre esses três será retornado.

```
Math.max(b,Math.max(c,a))
```

O mesmo é válido para obter o menor, porém, utilizando a função `Math.min`.

Comment: Que difícil. complicado

Comment: Acho que entendi. Aliás nao é tao difícil

Comment: @AlineGonzaga é simples, eu só não fiz assim porque acho que não é objetivo do exercícios usar coisas prontas, é testar sua capacidade de achar a solução e eu respondi como simplificar o que já tinha achado.

Comment: A classe Math é sua amiga em Java (assim como existe em outras linguagens). Você utilizará ela para várias coisas.

Comment: Obrigada. Vocês são legais.