# Nao encontro o menor numero

Tags: java

Boa tarde

Dado um inteiro não negativo
n e n números inteiros não negativos, indicar qual desses
números é o maior e qual o menor.

ate agora só consegui achar o maior será que alguém pode ajudar
Meu código abaixo:

```
package exe10ficha1;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Exe10ficha1 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num;
    int nums;
    int maior = 0;
    int menor = 0;
    int i;
    int aux;

    num = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Indique um valor"));

    if (num > 0) {
        for (i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
            nums = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Indique um valor"));

            if (nums <= 0) {
                System.out.println("O valor e invalido");
                System.exit(0);
            }

            if (nums >= maior) {
                maior = nums;
            } else {
                menor = nums;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("O maior e: " + maior);
    System.out.println("O menor e: " + menor);
}
```

}

Comment: Seria isso [Número maior e menor](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110753/91)  ?

Comment: Não por exemplo

Comment: digito 3 números
3,1,2

no resultado final aparece
O maior e 3
o menor e 2

Comment: if (nums >= maior) {
    menor = maior;
 maior = nums;
} else {
 menor = nums;
}

Comment: Não esta a funcionar

Answer (score 1):

Cara o mais fácil de fazer é adicionar seus números em um array de Inteiros de depois usar o Collections.min e Collections.max.

```
 if (num > 0) {
  Integer[] numbers = new Integer[num]
    for (i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
        numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Indique um valor"));

        if (numbers[i] <= 0) {
            System.out.println("O valor e invalido");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    int min = (int) Collections.min(Arrays.asList(numbers));
    int max = (int) Collections.max(Arrays.asList(numbers));

    System.out.println("O menor é: " + min);
    System.out.println("O maior é: " + max);
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Dot Net

Comment: São coisas quem anda sempre aprender, fiquei sem programar já algum tempo e retomei agora e estou com alguma dificuldade em recomeçar

Comment: Esta a funcionar perfeitamente Obrigrado