# Problema no algoritmo

Tags: java, if

> Enunciado: Leia 3 valores inteiros e ordene-os em ordem crescente. No final, mostre os valores em ordem crescente, uma linha em branco e em seguida, os valores na sequência como foram lidos.

```
public class ex10 {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Digite 3 valores em sequencia:");
    int v1 = x.nextInt();
    int v2 = x.nextInt();
    int v3 = x.nextInt();

    int um = 0;
    int dois = 0;
    int tres = 0;

    if(v1 < v2 && v1 <v3){
        um = v1;
    }if(v2 < v3){
        dois = v2;
        tres = v3;
    }else{
        tres = v2;
        dois = v3;
    }
    if(v2 < v1 && v2 < v3){
        um = v2;
    }if(v1 < v3){
        dois = v1;
        tres = v3;
    }else{
        dois = v3;
        tres = v1;
    }
    if(v3 < v2 && v3 < v1){
        um = v3;
    }if(v2 < v1){
        dois = v2;
        tres = v1;
    }else{
        dois = v1;
        tres = v2;
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println(um);
    System.out.println(dois);
    System.out.println(tres);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println(v1);
    System.out.println(v2);
    System.out.println(v3);


}

}
```

Meu problema é o seguinte, quando o usuário escreve os números do maior para o menor (6,5,4) ou do menor para o maior (4,5,6) o algoritmo funciona corretamente, mas quando o usuário põe fora de ordem, por exemplo 6,4,5 sai errado. Outra dúvida é se teria como fazer esse algoritmo de uma maneira mais resumida.

Comment: Joao, poste a solução como resposta, adicioanndo na pergunta você deixa ela confusa.

Comment: ok, vou fazer isso!

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Número maior e menor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/110753/n%c3%bamero-maior-e-menor)

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ex10 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Digite 3 valores em sequencia:");
        int a = x.nextInt();
        int b = x.nextInt();
        int c = x.nextInt();
        int v1 = a, v2 = b, v3 = c;

        // Se v1 for maior que v2, troca eles de lugar.
        if (v1 > v2) {
            int aux = v2;
            v2 = v1;
            v1 = aux;
        }

        // Se v1 for maior que v3, troca eles de lugar.
        if (v1 > v3) {
            int aux = v3;
            v3 = v1;
            v1 = aux;
        }

        // Se v2 for maior que v3, troca eles de lugar.
        if (v2 > v3) {
            int aux = v3;
            v3 = v2;
            v2 = aux;
        }

        System.out.println(v1 + ", " + v2 + ", " + v3);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(a + ", " + b + ", " + c);
    }
}
```

[Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.](http://ideone.com/cIaJr8)

A ideia é fazer com que `v1` tenha o menor valor. Para isso compara-se com `v2` e `v3`, trocando-se caso `v1` não seja o menor. Assim sendo, após essas duas etapas, `v1` vai ser o menor número.

Em seguida, `v2` deve ser o número do meio e `v3` o maior. Então é só compará-los e trocá-los se assim não for.

Note que você não precisa mostrar cada valor separadamente dos outros cada um em seu `System.out.println`. Você pode combinar uma linha inteira em cada `System.out.println`.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

resolução:

```
public class ex10 {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Digite 3 valores em sequencia:");
    int v1 = x.nextInt();
    int v2 = x.nextInt();
    int v3 = x.nextInt();

    int um = 0;
    int dois = 0;
    int tres = 0;

    if(v1 < v2 && v1 <v3){
        um = v1;
    if(v2 < v3){
        dois = v2;
        tres = v3;
    }else{
        dois = v3;
        tres = v2;
    }
    }
    if(v2 < v1 && v2 < v3){
        um = v2;
    if(v1 < v3){
        dois = v1;
        tres = v3;
    }else{
        dois = v3;
        tres = v1;
    }
    }
    if(v3 < v2 && v1 > v3){
        um = v3;
    if(v2 < v1){
        dois = v2;
        tres = v1;
    }else{
        dois = v1;
        tres = v2;
    }
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println(um);
    System.out.println(dois);
    System.out.println(tres);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println(v1);
    System.out.println(v2);
    System.out.println(v3);


}

}
```

meu erro foi ter fechado a chave muito cedo nessa parte:

```
if(v1 < v2 && v1 <v3){
    um = v1;
}if(v2 < v3){
    dois = v2;
    tres = v3;
```

fechei logo antes de por o segundo if, quando deveria ter deixado aberta

```
if(v1 < v2 && v1 <v3){
    um = v1;
if(v2 < v3){
    dois = v2;
    tres = v3;
```

Comment: Pode detalhar melhor o que você fez? Respostas com apenas código são pouco úteis a comunidade e geralmente agregam em nada.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Poderia me dar o link daquelas respostas no SOen que você disse?

Comment: @VictorStafusa https://stackoverflow.com/a/20600020/1452488, https://stackoverflow.com/a/19651476/1452488, https://stackoverflow.com/a/16826296/1452488. Em algumas há, de fato, algum comentário sobre, mas o consenso parece ser que é ok utilizar. Porém, eu não uso Java, então posso ter compreendido errado.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Não, isso é uma gambiarra bem horrorosa. Não é consenso que isso é ok de se usar, na verdade é consenso que isso **não** deve ser usado nunca.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss farei isso!